# Kill a cron Job

Tags: cron

In my server a cronjob is running every 30 min. The cronjob is executing a php script. If the cronjob is not completed within 30 min, I want to kill that cronjob on the execution of the cronjob next time.

Thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/270065/stop-an-already-running-cron-job

Answer (score 1):

Save the pid of the cron job to a file. After the required amount of time, kill the job using the saved pid and restart the job again.

Comment: Save in a file. After you wait a while read back from the file and kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use The Fat Controller to run a job every 30 minutes and specify that it should kill the previous job.   I'd say this is much easier and safer than creating your own form of process control.

There's plenty of documentation on the site but if you need any help configuring then just let me know.

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How can I do this in my server?